# Do white spaces take space in txt files?

Tags: c, file-io, whitespace, scanf

I'm wondering if the white spaces take space in `txt` files for C. For example if i'm going to take the file pointer back using `fseek()` or if I am going to `fscanf` an input from a file do I need to consider white spaces? A

Assume a file has this line:

```
michael 100 20 simon 200 30 daniel 300 100
```

If I want to scan the first data from the file in a loop should I do

```
fscanf(fp,"%s%d%d",structure[i].name,&structure[i].number1,&structure[i].number2);
```

or

```
fscanf(fp,"%s %d %d ",structure[i].name,&structure[i].number1,&structure[i].number2);
```

Also, do I need to consider these spaces while taking the file pointer back? For example to get to the second person in the file

```
fseek(fp,-sizeof(structure[i-1]),SEEK_CUR)
```

or

```
fseek(fp,-(sizeof(structure[i-1])+3),SEEK_CUR)//for there are 3 white spaces for each person.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your first question: No, white space does not need to be considered in `fscanf()`.

To your second question: Neither of these will work. You seem to be misunderstanding how information is stored in a computer. In the program, an integer is 32 bits (4 bytes), so `sizeof(int)` will always return 4. In a file, each character is one byte, so "314" takes 3 bytes, and "314159" takes 6. For this reason, it is usually not recommended to mix-and-match `fscanf` and `fseek`/`fgetc`.

Comment: could you provide any reference to the first answer? cplusplus.com(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/?kw=fscanf) and `man` states that spaces are needed. In practice (gcc 4.8.2) spaces does not matter.

Comment: cplusplus.com says: "the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character... A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none)." If whitespace in the input is ignored, and whitspace in the format can validate no whitespace, then it is not important.

Comment: IMHO the sentence you cited describes how fscanf behaves when it read whitespace from a format string. If there is no whitespace in format string at all, it should never goes to "Whitespace character" mode, thus space should not be discarded. That is you are right that there is no difference between one and two whitespace characters, but there is difference between one and no whitespaces at all.

Comment: @user3188346 I agree that the standard is not worded well, but there is a clear conclusion: let's assume that whitespace is necessary. Then "the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character" referencing the format string provides a contradiction; why is it ignored if it is necessary? If that sentence references the input stream, then whitespace is not necessary. Therefore, whitespace cannot be necessary. Further, as you mentioned, it is ignored in practice.

Comment: Thanks for clearing those out for me,then I assume I should be using fseek with fwrite and fread. Is there no way for me to get to somewhere in the middle of a txt file without using fseek?

Comment: @Mag You can combine them, but you should be careful. If you just need to get past the file header, which is always 200 bytes, then go ahead and use fseek. If each person is on their own line, use getline. But if the input is as you described, there is no efficient way; you will have to figure out how many characters are used to represent each person, and it would (almost always) just be more efficient to re-read the file (or store all the data in memory so that you don't need to).